# Result : Decimal point in nodes for categorical variables split in Rpart?

Tags: decision-tree, rpart

I got this from the model :

[image]

In the raw data set, the familygroup is a categorical variable and I have recode it into 1 to 5 according to different groups. Now the result shows a 1.5? Does it mean group 1 and group 5 observations are being combined? If yes, does it mean that group does not equal to group 1 and 5 are divert to the right node (<1.5) ? or the node is purely a numerical value that is 1.5? 
I have a few nodes that have these kind of results. 
This is the script that I used :

printcp(model) # display the results

rpart.plot(model,type = 3,tweak =1.5)

Thank you very much all advises.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have converted the 'familygroup' variable into a numeric variable when you re-coded it. Once you have done the re-coding, use this:

```
familygroup <- as.factor(familygroup)
```

And then run the rpart code  along with the plot. This should solve the problem.